# UserUpdateInfo | Error but not deprecated?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Trying to push variables to firebase, and when using the code block below, `UserUpdateInfo` and `updateUser` are throwing errors.

I tried doing some research into what is deprecated, and nothing came up sharing what is in replace of these items.

```
onPressed: () async {
          try {
            User user =
                (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _emailController.text,
              password: _passwordController.text,
            ))
                    .user;
            if (user != null) {
              UserUpdateInfo updateUser = UserUpdateInfo();
              updateUser.name = _nameController.text;
              user.updateProfile(updateUser);
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.menu);
            }
          }
```

Am I mistaken? What would this block look like if so?

Comment: Have you tried the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserUpdateInfo` was deprecated, you have to do the following:

```
if (user != null) {
 user.updateProfile(displayName : _nameController.text);
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.menu);
}
```

Check the source code:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/user.dart#L336